# How to use ByteArray for object serialisation and deserialisation

Tags: java, serialization

#### Context

I'm doing my student project and building a testing tool for regression testing.

Main idea: capture all constructors/methods/functions invocations using AOP during runtime and record all data into a database. Later retrieve the data, run constructors/methods/functions in the same order, and compare return values.

#### Problem

I'm trying to serialize objects (and arrays of objects) into a byte array, record it into PostgreSQL as a blob, and later (in another runtime) retrieve that blob and deserialize it back to object. But when I deserialize data in another runtime it changes and, for example, instead of `boolean`, I retrieve `int`. If I do exactly the same operations in the same runtime (serialize - insert into the database - SELECT from the database - deserialize) everything seems to work correctly.

Here is how I record data:

```
   private void writeInvocationRecords(InvocationData invocationData, boolean isConstructor) {
        final List<InvocationData> invocationRecords = isConstructor ? constructorInvocationRecords : methodInvocationRecords;
        final String recordsFileName = isConstructor ? "constructor_invocation_records.json" : "method_invocation_records.json";

        byte[] inputArgsBytes = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(invocationData.inputArgs);
            out.flush();
            inputArgsBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // ignore close exception
            }
        }

        byte[] returnValueBytes = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream rvBos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream rvOut = null;
        try {
            rvOut = new ObjectOutputStream(rvBos);
            rvOut.writeObject(invocationData.returnValue);
            rvOut.flush();
            returnValueBytes = rvBos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rvBos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // ignore close exception
            }
        }
        invocationRecords.add(invocationData);
        if (invocationRecords.size() >= (isConstructor ? CONSTRUCTORS_CACHE_SIZE : METHODS_CACHE_SIZE)) {
            List<InvocationData> tempRecords = new ArrayList<InvocationData>(invocationRecords);
            invocationRecords.clear();
            try {
                for (InvocationData record : tempRecords) {
                    SerialBlob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(inputArgsBytes);
                    SerialBlob rvBlob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(returnValueBytes);
                    psInsert.setString(1, record.className);
                    psInsert.setString(2, record.methodName);
                    psInsert.setArray(3, conn.createArrayOf("text", record.inputArgsTypes));
                    psInsert.setBinaryStream(4, blob.getBinaryStream());
                    psInsert.setString(5, record.returnValueType);
                    psInsert.setBinaryStream(6, rvBlob.getBinaryStream());
                    psInsert.setLong(7, record.invocationTimeStamp);
                    psInsert.setLong(8, record.invocationTime);
                    psInsert.setLong(9, record.orderId);
                    psInsert.setLong(10, record.threadId);
                    psInsert.setString(11, record.threadName);
                    psInsert.setInt(12, record.objectHashCode);
                    psInsert.setBoolean(13, isConstructor);
                    psInsert.executeUpdate();
                }
                conn.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how I retrieve data:

```
        List<InvocationData> constructorsData = new LinkedList<InvocationData>();
        List<InvocationData> methodsData = new LinkedList<InvocationData>();

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL_SELECT);
        while (rs.next()) {

            Object returnValue = new Object();
            byte[] returnValueByteArray = new byte[rs.getBinaryStream(7).available()];
            returnValueByteArray = rs.getBytes(7);
            final String returnType = rs.getString(6);
            ByteArrayInputStream rvBis = new ByteArrayInputStream(returnValueByteArray);
            ObjectInputStream rvIn = null;
            try {
                rvIn = new ObjectInputStream(rvBis);
                switch (returnType) {
                    case "boolean":
                        returnValue = rvIn.readBoolean();
                        break;
                    case "double":
                        returnValue = rvIn.readDouble();
                        break;
                    case "int":
                        returnValue = rvIn.readInt();
                        break;
                    case "long":
                        returnValue = rvIn.readLong();
                        break;
                    case "char":
                        returnValue = rvIn.readChar();
                        break;
                    case "float":
                        returnValue = rvIn.readFloat();
                        break;
                    case "short":
                        returnValue = rvIn.readShort();
                        break;
                    default:
                        returnValue = rvIn.readObject();
                        break;
                }
                rvIn.close();
                rvBis.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (rvIn != null) {
                        rvIn.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // ignore close exception
                }
            }

            Object[] inputArguments = new Object[0];
            byte[] inputArgsByteArray = new byte[rs.getBinaryStream(5).available()];
            rs.getBinaryStream(5).read(inputArgsByteArray);

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputArgsByteArray);
            ObjectInput in = null;
            try {
                in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
                inputArguments = (Object[])in.readObject();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (in != null) {
                        in.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // ignore close exception
                }
            }

            InvocationData invocationData = new InvocationData(
                    rs.getString(2),
                    rs.getString(3),
                    (String[])rs.getArray(4).getArray(),
                    inputArguments,
                    rs.getString(6),
                    returnValue,
                    rs.getLong(8),
                    rs.getLong(9),
                    rs.getLong(10),
                    rs.getLong(11),
                    rs.getString(12),
                    rs.getInt(13)
                    );
            if (rs.getBoolean(14)) {
                constructorsData.add(invocationData);
            } else {
                methodsData.add(invocationData);
            }
        }
        st.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
```

Comment: 1. You seem to regularly initialize a variable with some value only to overwrite it. For example `returnValue` is initialized to `new Object` only to be overwritten later on. And `returnValueByteArray` is initialized immediately before being overwritten by `rs.getBytes(7)`. Those initialization are unnecessary and pointless. 2. since you only use `writeObject()`, you should always use `readObject` to read the result.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend binary serialization since that can lead to problems like you're experiencing, e.g. if classes change between serialization and deserialization. Instead I'd suggest using JSON etc. Especially when you try to use your tool for regression testing you _will_ eventually make changes to classes that will make it hard to deserialize the data again. It might be hard with JSON already (e.g. what if required fields have been added or some field got redefined) but it's easier manageable and understandable since JSON is human readable.

Comment: @JoachimSauer 1. Yes, you are right, I will refactor it later. 2. Also good point, but I tried the `readOnject()` first, but later started trying other variants because I couldn't understand what is causing the problem.

Comment: @alectogeek: from your description I'd guess the most likely reason is that you're not actually reading the data that you think you are. So either you query the wrong thing or writing doesn't work as you expect it to. You say `int` and `boolean` get confused: do you usually write individual "simple" values (such as primitives or `String`) or more complex compound objects?

Comment: @Thomas Hmm. I didn't think about this side. So if I serialize an object as binary data, then I record not only information about its fields but also about its methods and constructors, right? And when I try to restore an instance of the class casting it to an already refactored class I might get errors or some unexpected behavior, right?

Comment: You wouldn't record the methods and constructors themselves, wouldn't you? Those are part of your code base and the compiler should capture any incompatible changes. However, I understood you'd want to capture calls to those as well as results. In that case you'd capture the call, the data of the parameters and the result (also data), try to replay the call for your test and compare the results.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I work both with primitives and complex objects (Map, Collection, Object). I also thought that I may not read what I expect, but I tried to use my reading algorithm right after recording the data into the database (in the same runtime) and everything worked well. I will check it one more time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explosion of errors and misguided ideas inherent in this question:

### Your read and write code is broken.

`available()` doesn't work. Well, it does what the javadoc says it does, and if you read the javadoc, and read it very carefully, you should come to the correct conclusion that what that is, is utterly useless. If you ever call `available()`, you've messed up. You're doing so here. More generally your read and write code doesn't work. For example, `.read(byteArr)` also doesn't do what you think it does. See below.

### The entire principle behind what you're attempting to do, doesn't work

You can't 'save the state' of arbitrary objects, and if you want to push the idea, then *if* you can, then certainly not in the way you're doing it, and in general this is advanced java that involves hacking the JDK itself to get at it: Think of an InputStream that represents data flowing over a network connection. What do you imagine the 'serialization' of this InputStream object should look like? If you consider serialization as 'just represent the underlying data in memory', then what you'd get is a number that represents the OS 'pipe handle', and possibly some IP, port, and sequence numbers. This is a tiny amount of data, and all this data is **completely useless** - it doesn't say anything meaningful about that connection and this data cannot be used to reconstitute it, at all. Even within the 'scope' of a single session (i.e. where you serialize, and then deserialize almost immediately afterwards), as networks are a stream and once you grab a byte (or send a byte), it's gone. The only useful, especially for the notion of 'lets replay everything that happened as a test', serialization strategy involves actually 'recording' all the bytes that were picked up, as it happens, on the fly. This is not a thing that you can do as a 'moment in time' concept, it's continuous. You need a system that is recording all the things (it needs to be recording every inputstream, every outputstream, every time `System.currentTimeMillis()` in invoked, every time a random number is generated, etc), and then needs to use the results of recording it all when your API is asked to 'save' an arbitrary state.

Serialization instead is a thing that objects need to opt into, and where they may have to write custom code to properly deal with it. Not all objects *can* even be serialized (an InputStream representing a network pipe, as above, is one example of an object that cannot be serialized), and for some, serializing them requires some fancy footwork, and the only hope you have is that the authors of the code that powers this object put in that effort. If they didn't, there is nothing you can do.

The serialization framework of java awkwardly captures both of these notions. It does mean that your code, even if you fix the bugs in it, will fail on most objects that can exist in a JVM. Your testing tool can only be used to test the most simplistic code.

If you're okay with that, read on. But if not, you need to completely rethink what you're going to do with this.

### ObjectOutputStream sucks

This is not just my opinion, the openjdk team itself is broadly in agreement (they probably wouldn't quite put it like that, of course). The data emitted by OOS is a weird, inefficient, and underspecced binary blob. You can't analyse this data in any feasible way other than spending a few years reverse engineering the protocol, or just deserializing it (which requires having all the classes, and a JVM - this can be an acceptable burden, depends on your use case).

Contrast to e.g. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) which serializes data into JSON, which you can parse with your eyeballs, or in any language, and even without the relevant class files. You can construct 'serialized JSON' yourself without the benefit of first having an object (for testing purposes this sounds like a good idea, no? You need to test this testing framework too!).

### How do I fix this code?

If you understand all the caveats above and somehow still conclude that this project, as written and continuing to use the ObjectOutputStream API is still what you want to do (I really, really doubt that's the right call):

Use the newer APIs. `available()` **does not** return the size of that blob. `read(someByteArray)` is **not** guaranteed to fill the entire byte array. Just read the javadoc, it spells it out.

There is no way to determine the size of an inputstream by asking that inputstream. You may be able to ask the DB itself (usually, `LENGTH(theBlobColumn)` works great in a SELECT query.

If you somehow (e.g. using LENGTH(tbc)) know the full size, you can use InputStream's [`readFully`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully(byte%5B%5D)) method, which will *actually* read all bytes, vs. `read`, which reads at least 1, but is not guaranteed to read all of it. The idea is: It'll read the smallest chunk that is available. Imagine a network pipe where bytes are dribbling into the network card's buffer, one byte a second. If so far 250 bytes have dribbled in and you call `.read(some500SizeByteArr)`, then you get 250 bytes (250 of the 500 bytes are filled in, and `250` is returned). If you call `.readFully(some500SizeByteArr)`, then the code will wait about 250 seconds, and then returns 500, and fills in all 500 bytes. That's the difference, and that explains why `read` works the way it does. Said differently: If you do not check what `read()` is returning, your code is definitely broken.

If you do *not* know how much data there is, your only option involves a `while` loop, or to call a helper method that does that. You need to make a temporary byte array, then in a loop keep calling read until it returns -1. For every loop, take the bytes in that array from 0 to (whatever the `read` call returned), and send these bytes someplace else. For example, a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

### Class matching

> when I deserialize data in another runtime it changes and, for example, instead of boolean, I retrieve int

The java serialization system isn't magically changing your stuff on you. Well, put a pin that. Most likely the class file available in the first run (where you saved the blob in the db) was different vs what it looked like in your second run. Voila, problem.

More generally this is a problem in serialization. If you serialize, say, `class Person {Date dob; String name;}`, and then in a later version of the software you realize that using a `j.u.Date` to store a date of birth is a very silly idea, as Date is an unfortunately named class (it represents an instant in time and not a date at all), so you replace it with a `LocalDate` instead, thus ending up with `class Person{LocalDate dob; String name;}`, then how do you deal with the problem that you now want to deserialize a BLOB that was made back when the `Person.class` file still had the broken `Date dob;` field?

The answer is: You can't. Java's baked in serialization mechanism will flat out throw an exception here, it will not try to do this. This is the `serialVersionUID` system: Classes have an ID and changing anything about them (such as that field) changes this ID; the ID is stored in the serialized data. If the IDs don't match, deserialization cannot be done. You can force the ID (make a field called `serialVersionUID` - you can search the web for how to do that), but then you'd still get an error, java's deserializer will attempt to deserialize a Date object into a `LocalDate dob;` field and will of course fail.

Classes can write their own code to solve this problem. This is non-trivial and is irrelevant to you, as you're building a framework and presumably can't pop in and write code for your testing framework's userbase's custom class files.

I told you to put a pin in 'the serialization mechanism isnt going to magically change types on you'. Put in sufficient effort with overriding serialVersionUID and such and you *can* end up there. But that'd be because you wrote code that confuses types, e.g. in your `readObject` implementation (again, search the web for java's serialization mechanism, readObject/writeObject - or just start reading the javadoc of `java.io.Serializable`, that's a good starting-off point).

### Style issues

You create objects for no purpose, you seem to have some trouble with the distinction between a variable/reference and an object. You aren't using try-with-resources. The way your SELECT calls are made suggests you have an SQL injection security issue. `e.printStackTrace()` as line line in a catch block is **always** incorrect.